# Windows C++ Thread Parameter Passing

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, function-pointers

In Windows c++, the following creates a thread:

```
CreateThread(NULL, NULL, function, parameter, NULL, &threadID);
```

This will run "function" in a new thread and pass it "parameter" as a void* or LPVOID.

Suppose I want to pass two parameters into "function", is there a better looking way of doing it besides creating a data structure that contains two variables and then casting the data structure as an LPVOID?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, that's the only way. Just create a struct with the 2 data members and pass that as void*

Comment: Are you sure? It seems so ugly to do it that way.

Comment: The idea behind having a `void*` as the parameter is so you can do just this, and the system doesn't get in the way. Your code knows what the parameter is on both sides, but the system doesn't have to.

Comment: @ross What's ugly about it? Remember you are constrained to provide a C interface. What's your better solution to the problem?

Comment: The void* doesn't technically need to contain pointer data, so you could use a `union thread_params { void* as_ptr; struct { short a, b; } as_fields; };` but that's much uglier and also riskier. Just put your parameters in a struct and pass a pointer to the struct. You can even template away the implementation if you like, or use a library that does this for you.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct PARAMETERS
{
    int i;
    int j;
};

DWORD WINAPI SummationThread(void* param)
{
    PARAMETERS* params = (PARAMETERS*)param;
    printf("Sum of parameters: i + j = \n", params->i + params->j);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    PARAMETERS params;
    params.i = 1;
    params.j = 1;

    HANDLE thdHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, SummationThread, &params, 0, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(thdHandle, INFINITE);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the standard way to pass a parameter to the thread however your new thread cann access any memory in the process so something that is difficult to pass or a lot of data can be accessed as a shared resource as long as you provide appropriate synchronization control.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a much better way, and I use it all the time in my embedded code. It actually grew out of the desire to pass a member method to a function that is very similar to CreateThread(). The reason that was desired was because the class already had as member data (with appropriate setters) all the parameters the thread code needed.  [I wrote up a more detailed explanation](http://tods-netburner-articles.wikia.com/wiki/Developing_in_C%2B%2B#Using_Class_Member_Functions_in_calls_to_the_OS) that you can refer to if you're interested. In the write-up, where you see OSTaskCreate(), just mentally substitute CreateMethod().

Comment: 2016 Dec 13, the link seem broken. Could you fix it please? @Tod

Comment: I'll see if I can get a copy of what I wrote. That wiki belongs to NetBurner and they are still in business and going strong so I'm not sure why they took the wiki down. I haven't done embedded work since I joined Pluralsight. I asked on their forum which can take a while before an employee sees it.

Comment: @Andiana Netburner kindly resurrected the wiki over the holiday so that I could get the articles. I copied the page of interest over to a wikia page and updated the link to point to the location on that page that should be of interest.